# How to modify specific Environment Variable with Pulumi Transformations

Tags: json, yaml, pulumi

I want to use pulumi transformations to update an environment variable value in a k8s manifest:

```
containers:
        - name: pgbouncer
          image: edoburu/pgbouncer:1.15.0
          env:
          # order of env vars should not change because pulumi code depends on it
          - name: DATABASE_URL
            value: 'psql://${username}:${password}@${endpoint}/${name}'
          - name: POOL_MODE
            value: 'transaction'
          - name: MAX_CLIENT_CONN
            value: '50'
          - name: ADMIN_USERS
            value: '${username}'
```

I did it by using the order or the environment variables See the following code, but I don't think it's good to keep it that way for its non-readability and error-prone in the future.

```
const pg_bouncer_reader = new k8s.yaml.ConfigFile("pg-bouncer-reader", {
    file: "../../pulumi-common/pg-bouncer.deployment.yaml",
    transformations: [
      (obj: any) => {
        obj.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[0].value = readerConnectionString;
        obj.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[3].value = defaultCluster.masterUsername;
      },
    ],
  });
```

is there a way to target YAML list element using syntax like `obj.spec.template.spec.containers[0].env[name = 'DATABASE_URL']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use any JavaScript method to search through lists. A colleague of mine (shoutout to Levi!) managed this using JavaScripts `.find` method:

```
const deployment = new k8s.yaml.ConfigFile("deployment", {
  file: "deployment.yaml",
  transformations: [
      (obj: any) => {
          obj.spec.template.spec.containers
              .find((container: any) => container.name === "pgbouncer")
              .env
              .find((env: any) => env.name === "DATABASE_URL")
              .value = readerConnectionString;
          obj.spec.template.spec.containers
              .find((container: any) => container.name === "pgbouncer")
              .env
              .find((env: any) => env.name === "ADMIN_USERS")
              .value = defaultCluster.masterUsername;
      },
  ],
});
```

Comment: That works, I thought YAML had something. Thanks to Levi and You!